# Display check marked taxonomies as drop down menu

Tags: taxonomy

I've built a hierarchical taxonomy that displays a master list of available fragrances in the admin. When you create a page, you checkmark the fragrances that are available for that particular post. I used this code to functions.php and it seems to work in the admin:

```
add_action( 'init', 'build_taxonomies', 0 );

function build_taxonomies() {
register_taxonomy(
'scents',
'page',
array( 'hierarchical' => true,
'label' => 'Scents',
'query_var' => true,
'rewrite' => true ) );
}
```

Now I need to output the checkmarked items so they display on the post in the form of a drop down menu.

The problem is that it outputs ALL scents that have been check marked across ALL pages. I just need it to output the ones that have been check marked on the page you're on.

Here's the code I used:

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories('taxonomy=scents'); ?>
```

How to edit this so that it only shows the fragrances for the page I'm on? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to display the taxonomies you selected in the admin UI when you display your custom post type in the frontend. What you will need to do in that case is to modify the template file that displays your post, and use something like (adapted from `content-single.php` under TwentyEleven:

```
<?php $scent_list = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'scents', '', ', ', '' ); 
      if ($scent_list): ?>
          <span class="scent-links">
              <?php printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Scents</span> %2$s', 'twentyeleven' ), 'entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-tag-links', $scent_list);
                    $show_sep = true; ?>
          </span>

<?php endif; // $artist_list ?>
```

This will display a list of the scents that are selected, but you could modify that output to show it as a dropdown list.

Comment: Thanks englebip! I dropped the code in and it worked perfectly! I've been trying to modify it to display as a select menu without any luck. Any chance you could show me an example of the above code as a menu?